# Finding intervals of increase/decrease after fundamental theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$$F(x)=\int_3^x\frac9{\ln(2t)}\,dt\text{, for }x\ge3$$

So I'm aware $F'(x)$ is $\frac9{\ln(2x)}$. The question is asking what interval $F$ is increasing and which interval range it is concave up. I thought increasing would be $(0, \infty)$, given that $F'$ is positive in that range. I then tried $(3, \infty)$, based on the the "for $x\ge3$ qualifier in the problem. No dice for either.

If you have the time as well, how would I find any local max/mins?

Comment: $F'(x)$ is not positive on $(0, \infty)$. $\ln(2x) > 0$ when $x > 1/2$

Comment: Also, there are no local max/min because $F'(x)$ can never be $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F'(x)=\frac9{\ln(2x)}$$
Since $\ln x \ge 0$ for $x \ge 1$, $F'(x) > 0$ for all $x \ge 3$.
$$F''(x)=-\frac9{x\ln^2(2x)}$$
Since $\ln x \ge 0$ for $x \ge 1$ and $\frac1x \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$, $F''(x)$ is convex for all $x \ge 3$.